# Run script on login (ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu

This is my first script, and really need some help

Here is what I have done so far.

```
tunctl
ifconfig tap0 192.168.255.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
sleep 10
/home/marius/./start.lab.sh
/home/marius/Dynamips/IE/./start_lab.sh
```

It works great when I run it from a terminal, but.......

I need a terminal to open upon startup and then run the above commands.

When "/home/marius/Dynamips/IE/./start_lab.sh" run it actually launches the app.

Now, can one send commands to the app in the terminal?

I ask allot, it would be awesome if someone can help

Regards,

Comment: Do you want to run the script in the background when the computer starts, or in a terminal when you login?

Comment: Hi 

Thanks for the help

In a terminal when I login

Answer (score 1):

In order to run your script when you log in, add a call to it at the end of your `~/.bash_profile` file.

For more information see the `Invocation` section of the Bash `man` page.

Answer (score 1):

The startup applications settings are in the system > preferences menu. You can add a new entry here for your script.

To run the script from a terminal enter the command as:

```
gnome-terminal --command /home/marius/Dynamips/IE/start_lab.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to run a script that opens a terminal -- You can just run your script in the background using the System -> Preferences menu.